# More than one widget that do different things - Android App

Tags: android

So Simply put I have one widget that is just one big button really, and on clicking it it does something. This works fine, however I now want to add more widgets to the app, they will all just be one button but each when clicked will need to do something else.
So far I have tired just copying the code I already have but it seems that when I click one of the widgets which ever I click first all the widgets will from then on do the same thing.

So really my question is how can I change the code to allow lots of widgets, or is there better code I should use (This code was taken from a guide and mashed up to work, I am by no means a Android expert)

Here is the code I have right now.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;


import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        Log.i("ExampleWidget",  "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(appWidgetIds));

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
        // provider
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("jackpal.androidterm", "jackpal.androidterm.Term"));
            intent.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.iInitialCommand", "su \n cd sdcard/backtrack \n sh backtrack.sh");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget1);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

            // To update a label

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
            // widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* what you want to do is to add more buttons to R.layout.widget1 then duplicate the code starting at Intent intent = new... once for each button, changing the intent to launch something else.
Best regards.